# Add a video to Photos app so that my XCUITest can pick it

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I am totally new to iOS testing. I have the below code.

```
import XCTest
final class UITests: XCTestCase {
    
    override func setUpWithError() throws
    {
        try super.setUpWithError()
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
    }

    
    func testCaption() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()

        app.launch()
        
        app.staticTexts["Choose a Video"].tap()
        
        app.scrollViews.otherElements.images["Video, three seconds, April 14, 3:34 PM"].tap()
```

This works fine when I manually add the video to the simulator before running the test. I am looking for a way to add the video to the simulator automatically before starting the test. Maybe in `setUpWithError()` method?

How the app works is: When    `app.staticTexts["Choose a Video"].tap()` is executed it opens the Photos app (screenshot attached). I need the video to be here already so that next line `app.scrollViews.otherElements.images["Video, three seconds, April 14, 3:34 PM"].tap()` can select it.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way yet @Afsal ? I'm also looking for same thing.

Comment: Yes I did, here's the code.

Add media: https://gist.github.com/afsal-backer/5fca21b5661d5bdf4e6d1e93311589a8

Remove media: https://gist.github.com/afsal-backer/42045e227615461ed7ce537f59cf8bc8

Comment: I added these as Pre-action and Post-action scripts on the Test Scheme.